# JSF with Cocoon

Tags: java, jsf, apache-cocoon

We research the possibility to migrate from a classic ASP to Java-based Web Application (namely JavaServer Faces 2.0).The old ASP application make use of XSLT to render basic UI components und we would like to keep using of the most of XSL stylesheets.
We would like to use Cocoon for implementing xml pipelines.

Has somebody practical experience with marrying JSF and Cocoon?
Are there any other similar frameworks for XML publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReXSL](http://www.rexsl.com), which is similar to Cocoon, but much simplier. It's an MVC framework, where Model is JAXB-annotated POJOs, View is XSL stylesheets, and Controller is JAX-RS resources.